# Extracting string/values from a large text/dat file

Tags: python, regex, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I want to extract the "Drops: XXXXX" from a text file whose text pattern looks something like this:

```
Pkts: 215104502  Bytes: 202537648280   Drops: 1302599
Pkts: 55330252  Bytes: 52018951784   Drops: 22086
Pkts: 46226143  Bytes: 42980694784   Drops: 0
Pkts: 52931264  Bytes: 49764764008   Drops: 0
Pkts: 60616843  Bytes: 57773237704   Drops: 1280513
Pkts: 215104502  Bytes: 202537648280   Drops: 1302599.
```

I am open to any pattern searching methodolofy ( grep,awk,python)

Thanks

Comment: grep "^Drops:\t\d" xxx.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` you could do:

```
awk '{ print $5, $6 }' text
```

Answer (score 2):

A few minutes of Googling would have found you that you need regular expressions and the ansewr would be something like

```
re.search(r'(?<=Drops: )\d+', input_string).group(0)
```